# PHP Export All Facebook Friends Email Address sdk 4.0

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the latest "Facebook SDK for php" https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4
and trying to pull all my friends (nane, email address), but unfortunately i'm getting only the friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app.

Here's my code:

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(APP_ID, APP_SECRET);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'http://xxxx/facebook' );

$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

if ( isset( $session ) ) {  

    $friends = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me/friends'))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
    echo '<pre>' . print_r( $friends, 1 ) . '</pre>';

} else {
    // show login url
    echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl(array('email', 'user_birthday', 'user_friends')) . '">Login</a>'; 
}
```

Any bub/solution to extract all the friends contacts??

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately that's normal with api v2.0 - there's no way to get a user's friends from applications created after 2014-04-30.

Comment: i think it's doable since **Peter Yang** talked about "access to non-app friends" in https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/04/30/the-new-facebook-login/

Comment: Yes, via the taggable and the invitable friends endpoints, but you only get their name and an invite/tag token.

Comment: https://www.cloudsponge.com/test-drive here a demo where you can import all your contacts with their email addresses, and the same result i'm getting in yahoo

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API does not give you access to your friends' email addresses in this manner.

You can access a user's email with the extended `email` permission (if they approve your permissions request), but that's it.

Comment: can you add a reference or provide more details?

Comment: @user1231317 Facebook doesn't provide a "things you can't do" page in their documentation, and I'm not sure what more details I can provide than "you can't" here.